# GCP Computer Engine disconnect me c# MSTSCLib

Tags: c#, google-compute-engine, rdp

I created an RDP client in c# and when I try to connect to a GCP instance  GCP Computer this its disconect me instant I using MSTSCLib.

I used this program with other servers and only with GCP instances I have this problem.

```
          try
             {
                 rdp.Server = "ip";
                 rdp.UserName = "user";
                 IMsTscNonScriptable secured = (IMsTscNonScriptable)rdp.GetOcx();
                 secured.ClearTextPassword = "password";
                 rdp.Connect();
             }
             catch (Exception Ex)
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("Error Connecting", "Error connecting to remote desktop " + " Error:  " + Ex.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
             }
```

disconnect function

```
private void Rdp_OnDisconnected(object sender, AxMSTSCLib.IMsTscAxEvents_OnDisconnectedEvent e)
        {
            this.close();
        }
```

Comment: What does the exception say?

Comment: Could you explain in more details what is the problem that happens?

Comment: The exception dont say nothing just close the app

Comment: i wrote a function when the server is disconnected close the app